# How much macronutrient do we lost w.r.t the body activity?

Tags: nutrition, food, nutrition-information

I'm currently developing a (personal and non-profit) web app where I store and make stats from nutrition and activity data. In this app I enter every single meal I eat or activity I do in order to follow a kind of "global health score".

To complete some graphs, I need to know how much proteins, carbohydrates and fat are lost w.r.t to the body activity.

Despite some searches on the internet I didn't find any resource.
Is there some papers or tables I can use to compute those stats ?

Comment: We don't "lose" proteins, carbohydrates, and fat. We eat them and convert them to other materials (and energy). You're probably thinking of caloric expenditure?

Comment: @Alec "lose" may not be the good word, I should have said "consumed". If I understand what both of you are saying, we can know the amount of calories lost due to an activity, but it's hard (impossible) to know how fat, carbs and proteins are consumed by the body ?

Comment: You need to expand your understanding of the process. ATP is what the cell uses for energy The body uses glucose to create more ATP. The stored form of glucose is glycogen. All the body's digestive processes exist to convert fats, protein and carbs to glycogen. And, some people are more efficient at this, some are worse, etc. What you're asking is not really quantifiable in an app, I don't think. As @POD and Alec say, it's extraordinarily complex.